# CCLabelTTF disappear after CCSequence

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, label, sequence

me need you advice. In my GameScene i've got a point label **curentPointsLabel**. To update i've got a function, but after performance **updateCurentPoints** (CCSequence) the point label is disappear! why?

in init

```
_curentPointsLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(screenSize.width*0.17f, screenSize.height*0.1f) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"Trebuchet MS" fontSize:15];
_curentPointsLabel.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
_curentPointsLabel.position =  ccp( screenSize.width-screenSize.height/20, screenSize.height-2*screenSize.height/20);
_curentPointsLabel.color = ccc3(0,0,0);
[self addChild:_curentPointsLabel];
```

when i want update points label I do

```
- (void)updateCurentPoints:(int)points {

    if(_curentPoints+points<0)
        _curentPoints=0;
    else
        _curentPoints=_curentPoints+points;

   // [_curentPointsLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",_curentPoints]];

    NSString * valueString=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",_curentPoints]] retain];

    id sequence=[CCSequence actions:
                [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(setLabelColor:withIndex:) data:(void*)1],
                [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(setLabelValue:withValue:) data:(NSString*)valueString],
                [CCBlink actionWithDuration:0.5f blinks:2], 
                [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(setLabelColor:withIndex:) data:(void*)3],

                 nil];

    [_curentPointsLabel runAction:sequence];

    [valueString release];
}

//*******************************************************************
-(void) setLabelValue:(id) sender withValue:(NSString*) value
{   
    CCLabelTTF *label=(CCLabelTTF *)sender;
    NSString * valueString=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value]] retain];
    [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",valueString]];
    [valueString release];
}
//*******************************************************************
-(void) setLabelColor:(id) sender withIndex:(int)index
{   
    CCLabelTTF *label=(CCLabelTTF *)sender;

    if(index==0)
        label.color = ccc3(255,255,255);//white
    else if(index==1)
        label.color = ccc3(0,255,0);//green
    else if(index==2)
        label.color = ccc3(255,0,0);//red
    else if(index==3)
        label.color = ccc3(0,0,0);//black
    NSLog(@"color:%i",index);
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant to your original question, but you have unnecessary initialization of `NSString`s and redundant `retain`s in your code.

Comment: Can you see the label blink during the whole process? Or does it directly disappear?

Comment: Yes, i can see, but when blink done the label disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [CCShow action] to make sure the sprite is visible. Try this:

```
id sequence=[CCSequence actions:
             [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(setLabelColor:withIndex:) data:(void*)1],
             [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(setLabelValue:withValue:) data:(NSString*)valueString],
             [CCBlink actionWithDuration:0.5f blinks:2], 
             [CCShow action],
             [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(setLabelColor:withIndex:) data:(void*)3],
             nil];
```

Also test with changing the number of blinks from 2 to 3 ( or other odd numbers except 1). Either of the solution should work.